# Doit-on utiliser « de » dans « le prix est de… » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, unités

> C'est un pantalon un peu cher. Son prix est **de** 80 euros.

Pourquoi ne pas dire simplement « le prix est 80 euros » ? Est-ce que la phrase reste correcte même sans utiliser *de* ?

Comment: On entend même, plutôt de la part des vendeurs: "son prix est à 80 euros", ou "ce pantalon est à 80 euros".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il n'est pas obligatoire de dire d'un prix qu'il est *de* tant d'argent.

C'est une tournure très courante, mais dire *le prix de cette voiture est 10 000 euros* est tout aussi correct, du moins à ce qu'il me semble, et ne me choque pas.

Je n'ai rien trouvé à ce sujet dans le TLF ni dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie Française.

Comment: "Le prix de cette voiture est 10000 euros" est probablement correct, mais cette tournure sans "de" sonne bancale à mon oreille. Je ne sais pas si cet avis est partagé.

Answer (score 5):

Peut-être parce que l'on dit « Un prix de 80 euros »

Je ne connais pas la forme grammaticale / linguistique qui en est l'origine, mais on la retrouve dans d'autres expressions:

> Une hauteur de 2,30 m. / La hauteur est de 2.30 m.
>
> Un bilan de 42 victimes. / Le bilan est de 42 victimes.
>
> Un budget de 80 millions d'euros. / Le budget est de 80 millions d'euros.

J'imagine alors que le « de » est maintenu en présence d'un verbe.

Comment: En réfléchissant à tes exemples, je me dis qu'il y a peut-être une règle avec les compléments circonstanciels de mesure... Malgré mes recherches, je ne la trouve pas, mais ça semble possible !

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Non, on dit toujours "le prix est de 80 euros".</strike>

Je **pense** que c'est parce qu'il y a une ellipse, ce serait en fait "le prix est (d'une valeur) de 80 euros". On peut dire plein d'autres choses sur le prix, en dehors de sa valeur, "le prix est élevé", "le prix est inconnu",...

Comment: On le dit très souvent, mais pas toujours, Marie. Après, je ne trouve aucune source documentant cet usage, ni permettant de déterminer si l'une de ces tournures est incorrecte.

Comment: Tu as raison, c'est vrai que je ne trouve pas de source non plus... Mais ça sonne faux, "le prix est 80 euros", "la longueur est 5 mètres" non ? Je suis d'accord avec l'explication d'Alexis Pigeon, on dit "un prix de 80 euros", il semble donc logique de reprendre la même structure.

Comment: Je dirais que ça dépend du contexte. C'est vrai que "le prix est 5 euro", d'emblée, fait drôle. Maintenant, si je demande le prix d'une réparation à mon garagiste et qu'il me répond "le prix de cette réparation est 800 euro", cette phrase ne me choque pas, je ne trouve pas qu'elle sonne faux. (Je prends cet exemple car c'est l'un de ceux, et vécu, que j'avais en tête au moment de répondre).

De même, pour la réponse d'Alexis: j'ai déjà entendu, et probablement dit "le budget de cette année est xxxxxxx €". De même pour la hauteur. "De" est courant, mais n'est pas absolu.

Answer (score 2):

Dans la phrase :

"Le prix d'une vache est (égale au prix) de 4 moutons ou (égale au prix) de 1000 poules"

il n'est pas possible de supprimer les "de". Si l'on paye en euros par commodité, ce n'est cependant qu'une unité comme les autres, il n'y a pas plus de raison de supprimer le "de".