# What is rule of saying using de after "Le prix de la salade de tomates..."

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, partitif

Generally with food we use du, de la, de l' and des according to the Gender and Number. In this case is, de+la=de la, or is it simply de+ la salade de tomates? What I mean to ask is that whether the "de" used in this context is strictly equivalent to "of" or does it have to do with what the "thing" is?

PS: I read the answers to this [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6616/doit-on-utiliser-de-dans-le-prix-est-de) but couldn't understand the answers. I would request the community to answer in English as I am still learning French.

Answer (score 2):

In this case *de* is a preposition used to complement the noun *prix*. It is not partitive article used to indicate a certain amount. In your terms indeed it is simply “de” (which translates to *of*) followed by “la salade de tomates”.

What happens in the question you linked is quite different because the complement does not come right next to the noun but is provided as an attribute after the verb *être*. Moreover “Le prix est de” can only be used to indicate the amount not the object whose price is mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for replying (en anglais!). I just want to check my understanding: If I have to say that-The price of cucumbers is 30 euros, then is the following French translation correct:- "Le prix de les concombres est trente euros.?"

Comment: “De + les” is always contracted to “des”, both when *de* is a preposition or a partitive article. Therefore, you would say “le prix des concombres” instead.

Comment: Okay, I'll remeber that...Will "The price of one cucumber is 30 euros" be equal to "Le prix d'un concombre est trente euros" in French.

Comment: Yes… but 30 euros is awefully expensive for a cucumber :-)